# Make a textbox content editable false in a dynamic table for HTML using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, input, contenteditable

I am trying to make the first cell in my dynamic table not editable but I am having no luck. According to my knowledge, this should be right but for some reason it's not working right.

```
var n = 1;
function addRow(tableID,column) {
    var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

    for(i=0;i<column;i++){

        var cell = row.insertCell(i);
        var element = document.createElement("input");
        element.type = "text";
        element.name = n+"0"+i;
        element.size = "12";
        element.id = n+"0"+i;
        element.value = element.id;
        if(element.id == n+"00"){
            element.contenteditable = "false";
            element.value = "false";
            //alert("false");
        }
        cell.appendChild(element);
    }
    n++;
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

n is the number of the row

I am getting "false" for value of the first cell, meaning is entering the if statement, but it's not reading the `contenteditable="false"`.

Like always, any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input elements don't need `contenteditable`. Just use

```
element.disabled = true;
```

to disable it.

Comment: thanks! it worked great! but the color of the text is grey, I guess I'll have to edit it through CSS?

Comment: That's a known issue. You can't apply styling to a disable input field. Some newer browser might allow it but I'm not sure if all browsers do.